# I set default value on my migration but When I am create and not giving any value it's showing error

Tags: laravel, database-migration

**I set commission default as 0.00. But when I insert the data but don't give any on commission. it's giving an error that commission can't be null.**

```
*Here is my migration code:* 
    
    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('pc_lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('name')->nullable();       
                $table->decimal('commission')->default('0.00');
                $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');                    
            });
        }
    
    *My blade code is here:*   
     
                 <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="" method="POST" 
                           enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                         <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="commission">Commission (%)</label>
                                <input type="number" min="0" name="commission" 
                            class="form-control" >
                            </div>                            
                 <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col" style="margin-top: 29px !important;">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
                       value="Add Personal" >                                   
                            </div>
                        </div>            
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please add controller snippet to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting string to integer and decimal don't use '' on default.

```
 public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('pc_lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('name')->nullable();       
                $table->decimal('commission')->default(0.00);
                $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);                    
            });
        }
```